# How to set up direction of three.js PointerLockControls?

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d

I am using three.js PointerLockControls.  https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/controls/PointerLockControls

I set the camera to be z-axis is the up down axis.

```
camera.up.set(0,0,1);
```

However, I find that when I move the mouse cursor left and right, the screen rotates along the y axis instead of the z-axis. How can I fix this?

```
        const controls = new PointerLockControls( camera, document.body );
        controls.addEventListener('lock', () => (menuPanel.style.display = 'none'))
        controls.addEventListener('unlock', () => (menuPanel.style.display = 'block'))
        startButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
            controls.lock();
        }, false);
```